# Firebase throwing "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete" exception inside onComplete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-livedata

Hello i have a situation here, I have a custom `FirebaseAuthLiveData` class extending `Livedata` and implements `OnCompleteListener`. this class basically does all the authentication related work with firebase. I’m following mvvm architecture for the app. so i’ll be observing the livedata from activity. Now the problem is i’m getting `Task Not Complete yet` exception when i try to save the value of livedata in `oncomplete`  but when i reopen the app again it’s already logged in..I have attached the class, if anyone can point out what i’m doing wrong,
the firebase version i’m using is 11.8.0

```
class FirebaseAuthLiveData (private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) : LiveData<Resource<FirebaseUser>>(), OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>, OnFailureListener{

    override fun onFailure(p0: Exception) {
       value = Resource.error(p0.localizedMessage,null)
    }


    override fun onComplete(p0: Task<AuthResult>) {

        Log.d("firebase auth", "is task successful : "+p0.isSuccessful);
        if (p0.isSuccessful) {
            value = Resource.success(p0.result.user)
        }
    }

    //this is called from a viewmodel
    fun signInAnonymously( ){

        firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously()
               .addOnFailureListener(this)
               .addOnCompleteListener(this)

    }
}
```

and here is the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.creoit.android.withdrawalwarrior, PID: 10246
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.zzbjk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.creoit.android.withdrawalwarrior.prior_info.PriorInfoContentActivity$signInAnonymouslyWithFirebase$1.onChanged(PriorInfoContentActivity.kt:124)
    at com.creoit.android.withdrawalwarrior.prior_info.PriorInfoContentActivity$signInAnonymouslyWithFirebase$1.onChanged(PriorInfoContentActivity.kt:33)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:148)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:294)
    at com.creoit.android.withdrawalwarrior.firebase.livedata.FirebaseAuthLiveData.onComplete(FirebaseAuthLiveData.kt:28)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kS2S.png)Check you have given access to the firebase to sign in Anonymously. 
TO do that goto Firebase Authentication/Sign In Method then enable the sign in Anonymously switch button.

Answer (score 0):

put while ((!uri.isComplete())); like this .

```
 reference.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override

                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                toast("Entered success listner");
                                Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                                 while ((!uri.isComplete()));
                                Uri url = uri.getResult();
                                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
                                PDFDoc uploadpdf = new PDFDoc(name.getText().toString(), url.toString());
                                databaseReference.child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(uploadpdf);

                                toast("Uploaded to database");
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
```

this worked for me :)